# Table lock while transaction is not committed in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have come up with a scenario in which I am saving data using transaction using Entity Framework in C#. The table lock while it is not commit. I am using below code to save data.

```
tblCharge obj = new tblCharge();
obj.Plan = "DD";
obj.TotalAmount = 1500;

// Opening transaction
using (System.Data.Common.DbTransaction transaction((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext.Connection.BeginTransaction())
{
     dbContext.tblCharges.Add(obj);
     dbContext.SaveChanges();
     transaction.Commit();
}
```

When I am saving data before commit and I make selection query from table in SQL Server, it doesn't show results till the transaction commit.

Is there any way that table locking not occur while using transaction?

Comment: It's **not** a table lock - only those rows that you're inserting are being locked. The rest of the table is still available for selection - no problem. At this locking behavior is **on purpose** and for good reason - don't try to circumvent it!

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of transactions in a relational database is to make the changes being performed to the database invisible to other transactions until the transaction is committed. So to answer your question, no it is not possible to have the results visible to other queries before the transaction is committed because this would violate the main definition of what a transaction is.

Comment: But the point is all other data should be available for selection. Is there anyway to do it.

Comment: @AlinaDilshad: the data **IS** available for selection - as soon as the transaction has **committed it** and thus the data is really stored for good. Before the commit, the data isn't really in the database yet..... and so you shouldn't be wanting to select it before the commit !